# How to create a shortcut to a document on Lubuntu desktop?

Tags: lubuntu, symbolic-link

I am trying to create a shortcut for a word document (`.docx`) on Lubuntu desktop (22.04 LTS). I thought I could create a symlink as follows:

```
ln -s a.docx ~/Desktop/
```

The symlink does get created and show up as a shortcut on the desktop. But it seems that Lubuntu does not treat it as a shortcut. When I double-click `a.docx` on Desktop, Lubuntu asks me to choose a program to open the symlink as shown in the screenshot below.

*What is the right way to create a shortcut on Lubuntu desktop?*

[image]

Comment: https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/5/5.2/desktop_icons.html?highlight=shortcut

Answer (score 1):

@ARG's answer about creating a `.desktop` file works.

Additionally, as pointed out in the comments and the [documentation](https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/5/5.2/desktop_icons.html?highlight=shortcut), this can also be done via drag-and-drop onto the desktop and then choosing `Create symlink here` from the context menu.

> You can also create shortcuts by dragging and dropping files and
> folders from the File manager onto the desktop.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for writing this up  (*and link to Lubuntu manual*)

Comment: @guiverc Thank you. :)